# How to add empty Caption in ASP.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, caption

Whenever I set caption property to blank in an ASP.net gridview it does not show up in html. how can I add empty caption in gridview so that in html it shows up as `<caption/>` rather than not showing up at all.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server" Caption="">
```

Comment: Hope this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858494/styling-a-gridview-caption-from-c-sharp-class

Answer (score 0):

Can you please say in more details, why you require  tag if there is  no any text for the grid or table header?

If you require it by specific reason then you can add the space as below in your code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server" Caption=" ">
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The main reason i want to add a blank one because a the screen reader can say its an empty caption. Putting an empty space will add another line in html. also the screen reader will read it as blank and may confuse disabled people.